# Messages stay in exim4 queue for too long?

Tags: exim

I'm a little confused about the message queue on exim4. I believe that a particular message has been in the queue for 21 days:

```
$ sudo exim -bp | head -n 2
21d  5.2K 1YU9Ma-0007Ow-Hf <xx@xxx.com>
          xxx@yahoo.com
```

However, this doesn't seem to make sense given the retry rules that are in place (which I think should stop retrying after 4 days):

```
$ sudo exim -brt yahoo.com
Retry rule: *  *  F,2h,15m; G,16h,1h,1.5; F,4d,6h;
```

What's going on here?  I searched my logs for this message id and found nothing but this:

```
$ zgrep 1YU9Ma-0007Ow-Hf /var/log/exim4/mainlog*
/var/log/exim4/mainlog:2015-03-27 12:54:09 1YU9Ma-0007Ow-Hf == xxx@yahoo.com routing defer (-51): retry time not reached
/var/log/exim4/mainlog:2015-03-27 12:54:13 1YU9Ma-0007Ow-Hf == xxx@yahoo.com routing defer (-51): retry time not reached
/var/log/exim4/mainlog:2015-03-27 14:41:16 1YU9Ma-0007Ow-Hf == xxx@yahoo.com routing defer (-51): retry time not reached
/var/log/exim4/mainlog:2015-03-27 14:42:08 1YU9Ma-0007Ow-Hf == xxx@yahoo.com routing defer (-51): retry time not reached
/var/log/exim4/mainlog:2015-03-27 14:43:23 1YU9Ma-0007Ow-Hf == xxx@yahoo.com routing defer (-51): retry time not reached
/var/log/exim4/mainlog.1:2015-03-26 13:52:25 1YU9Ma-0007Ow-Hf == xxx@yahoo.com routing defer (-51): retry time not reached
...
```

Is there a reason a message would remain in the queue so long after its retry timeout has expired?

Answer (score 0):

Would you happen to have a log showing when the email was first attempted?

In most cases which I have seen this in the past, an exim is attempting to send an email to an address that does not exist or an email is coming in to a email account that does not exist. Unless you specify in the configuration for messages sent to inactive emails to be "blackholed", this will occur and manual cleanup is required. Alternatively, you may run the following:

```
exim -Mrm <message-id>
```

This will remove the email.

Comment: Unfortunately my oldest log is from Mar 19, so I can't check on this particular message.  However, for `1YZYcZ-00056T-Eo` (which has been in the queue for 6d), I see these lines at the bottom: `<= xx@xxx.com U=xx P=local S=20377` and `== xxx@yahoo.com R=dnslookup defer (-1): host lookup did not complete`